# Use awk to print only the IP and OPEN ports field

Tags: awk, nmap

I'd like to print only the IP address and open ports field from a given a gnmap file.

```
Host: 123.123.123.123 ()  Ports: 80/open/tcp//http?///, 443/open/tcp//https?///, 8083/closed/tcp//us-srv///, 65001/closed/tcp/////        Ignored State: filtered (65531) Seq Index: 262  IP ID Seq: Randomized
Host: 123.123.123.124 ()  Ports: 80/open/tcp//http?///, 443/open/tcp//https?///, 10443/open/tcp//https///, 65001/closed/tcp/////        Ignored State: filtered (65531) Seq Index: 262  IP ID Seq: Randomized
Host: 123.123.123.125 ()  Ports: 80/open/tcp//http?///, 443/open/tcp//https?///, 8083/closed/tcp//us-srv///, 8445/open/tcp//https///, 65001/closed/tcp/////        Ignored State: filtered (65531) Seq Index: 262  IP ID Seq: Randomized
Host: 123.123.123.126 ()  Ports: 1337/open/tcp//https?///, 8083/closed/tcp//us-srv///, 65001/closed/tcp/////        Ignored State: filtered (65531) Seq Index: 262  IP ID Seq: Randomized
```

Expected output is

```
123.123.123.123 80/open/tcp//http?///, 443/open/tcp//https?///
123.123.123.124 80/open/tcp//http?///, 443/open/tcp//https?///, 10443/open/tcp//https///
123.123.123.125 80/open/tcp//http?///, 443/open/tcp//https?///
```

I have already tried a number of different commands, one among which is the below command.

```
cat targets_osdetection.gnmap | awk '/open/{print $2 " " $5 " "$6 " " $7}'
```

But it only prints the fields corresponding to the $Number field and since each IP may not have same number of open ports, this command is not so efficient.

Can someone please provide the awk solution for this?

Comment: `8445/open/tcp//https///` was missed from your 3rd output line. Why?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt notice it. But definitely meant that all open ports to be included in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bsh
awk '/\/open\//{
  l=$2
  for (i=3;i<=NF;++i) {
    if ($i~/\/open\//) l=l" "$i;
  };
  print l
 }'
```

**Explanation:**

If `/open/` matches the line:

1. Create a variable with the IP (`$2`)
2. Loop through fields `$3`-`NF` and add the field to the variable if `/open/` matches.
3. Print the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a static file format `sed` substitution will also do the job:

```
sed -E 's/(Host:|Ports:|\(\)) +|[^ ]+closed[^ ]+| +Ignored State:.*//g' targets_osdetection.gnmap
```

The output:

```
123.123.123.123 80/open/tcp//http?///, 443/open/tcp//https?///,  
123.123.123.124 80/open/tcp//http?///, 443/open/tcp//https?///, 10443/open/tcp//https///, 
123.123.123.125 80/open/tcp//http?///, 443/open/tcp//https?///,  8445/open/tcp//https///, 
123.123.123.126 1337/open/tcp//https?///,
```